# How do I backup SQL Server Agent configuration?

Tags: sql-server

I've tried googling for this.  The problem is that the all the results are about using SQL Server Agent to schedule automatic backups.

How do I backup the SQL Server Agent configuration itself?  If my database machine fails, I will need to recreate all the SQL Server Agent jobs that are currently defined.  Is all this information stored in the Master database and is a restore of that database all that is required to get the SQl Server Agent jobs back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are actually all in the `msdb` database. However, it's not advisable to simply restored `msdb` over the existing one. The best solution is to script the jobs out on a weekly baseis. Take a look at this for some example steps on how to backup/restore jobs

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic749226-146-1.aspx#bm749280

Comment: +1 Deleted my answer, as this one is much more complete.

Comment: Scripting out your jobs can be added management if you have a large number of jobs. I would probalby just increase the number of backups to msdb if changes are made freqently. Which you could just do a trigger or something to catch when a new job is added, then fire off a backup (not that I've done this).

Comment: Is it possible to set up a sql agent job to script out all the sql agent jobs each week?  1/2 ;^)